# What does backward slash mean when present in a filepath?

Tags: python

I am curious about what \ Jun/ means in the code below. Does this mean the filepath can include Jun at the end? But if it doesn't, will it understand /MY/FILE/PATH/2019/19-6 is the Jun folder?

I tried googling it, but I am not sure what exactly it's called.

```py
year = 2019
month = 6

mnts = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
mnt = int(month) - 1

file_path = "/MY/FILE/PATH/" + str(year) + "/" + str(year)[-2:] + "-" + str(month) + "\ " + mnts[mnt] + "/"

print(file_path)
/MY/FILE/PATH/2019/19-6\ Jun/
```

When setting the variable `file_path` to the June file_path, is the filepath be `/MY/FILE/PATH/2019/19-6\ Jun/` or `/MY/FILE/PATH/2019/19-6/` based on the way the `\` is here?

Comment: It's escaping the space.

Comment: It's not actually escaping the space, but it might be passing an escape sequence to an OS call later, in code not shown. It probably should be the equivalent "\\ " to be correct python, and to make it more clear what it is actually doing. But really the other code should be putting quotes around it, and not care what is in file_path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the path is lacking quotes, the backslack is escaping the space character. `/MY/FILE/PATH/2019/19-6\ Jun/` is equivalent to `"/MY/FILE/PATH/2019/19-6 Jun/"`

Comment: This is not a recognized escape sequence in https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals which also says "all unrecognized escape sequences are left in the string unchanged" If it gets passed to the OS, then whether those two are equivalent is ... up to the OS

Comment: Good catch @KennyOstrom, I have confirmed it's not passed to the OS in my case. Thanks for the lookout though.